# Dropdown's SelectedIndexChanged event is not fired when its populated from client side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, selectedindexchanged

I have a dropdown on my page which I am populating from client side javascript code. The `SelectedIndexChanged` does not fire. But when I populate my dropdown from code behide (.cs file) the even is fired.

Any idea how to handle `SelectedIndexChanged` when dropdown is being populated from code behind. I could see that dropdown is getting populated as per my needs. Only `SelectedIndexChanged` even is not getting fired. Also note that the drop down is inside `UpdatePanel`. Will that be a reason?

Here is my html, javascript and code behind event:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddS" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddS_SelectedIndexChanged"
                AutoPostBack="True" Style="position: absolute; width: 50%;">
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#ddS').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
```

**CS**

```
protected void ddS_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
My main reason behind doing this is:
I have used `jquery ui js` for a popup, it has a multi-select drop down list. Since the button in a popup cannot have a server side event I have used ajax call to a web-method in .cs file. This method will update my tables from the database with the options selected in the multi-select drop down. Once it is done I want to close the popup and populate a drop down based on the options selected in multi-select.

I cannot populate my dropdown from code behind because the web-method is a static method and hence any method called from that method has to be a static method. If I write a static method then I cannot access UI controls(my drop down) from a static method. So I was hoping I can populate it from JS and then trigger my indexchange event for further computation.

Comment: did this `#ddS` has attribute : `runat="server"` ?

Comment: @demo yes it has `runat` attribute. Check my HTML above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is don't do this.  This is not how ASP.NET Server Controls were designed to work and you will end up creating a Rube Goldburg making it work.  Details below:

ASP.NET has a security feature (Event Validation) built in to prevent data being posted that was not present in the control after the Render stage of the page life-cycle.  If this occurs an ArgumentException will be thrown.  You can disable event validation or override Render and stick lots of code in your Page_Load function, but I wouldn't recommend it.

So why does all of this happen?  ASP.NET Server controls use ViewState in an attempt to create state like the state in a desktop application (Windows Forms => Web Forms see what they did there).  ViewState gets upset if it doesn't know about the `<options>` you added to the `<select>`.  A few solutions are:

1) Populate the DropDownList on the Server-Side (unless you have a very good reason not to) and let the ASP.NET Framework do what it was intended to do (you *may* also have to add the EnableViewState=true attribute to the DropDownList control although I believe it is the default).  If the DropDownList is in an update panel ViewState is updated form the PartialPostBack triggered by the panel so the ViewState stays happy while you get flicker-free updates.

2) Forget the Server-side code and create and populate the `<select>` control using JavaScript.

a) You can bind a JavaScript event listener to update a hidden field when the selected item is changed.  Then on PostBack you can read the value of the hidden field to get the value of the last selected item.

b) You can bind a JavaScript event listener to run a POST or GET (AJAX Request) when the selection changes if you need to communicate those changes with the server-side code.  You never really said what your objective is...

EDIT AFTER QUESTION UPDATE:

There are three ways I can think of:

1)  Remove the ASP `DropDownList` control and make it a regular HTML `select` control.  Give the control a name (use the name attribute not just the id attribute). ex:

```
<select name='options'></select>
```

On POST, HttpContext.Current.Request.Form is a NameValueCollection that will contain Key-Value pairs of the POSTed data.  you should be able to get the selected items from your select control by using the name you gave the `select` control:

```
var options = HttpContent.Current.Request.Form["options"].Split(',');
```

options will now be a list of the selected values.  If you need this to be AJAX enabled (no page refresh) wrap it in an `UpdatePanel`.

2) Write the selected items to a hidden field and collect the values from the hidden field on POST.

3) Trigger a POST to a Web Method that updates a session object which can then be read from inside your non-static code behind class members/methods.  There is an optional attribute for the Web Method decoration that enables session:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I will try to implement what U have said. Please refer to edited part of my question to know more details about my problem.

Comment: Are you doing a POST/GET to refresh your table data (page refresh) or are you using AJAX or an UpdatePanel?

Comment: I have used POSt method

Answer (score -1):

Generally, you need to make sure that your event handlers (your SelectedIndexChanged) are set **after all DOM operations**. In your case you append your html element by jQuery's append method. Unfortunately, adding callbacks to that method is not possible. 
A settimeout with the timer "1ms" however always puts the function in the settimeout on the bottom of the call stack.

```
$('#ddS').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
setTimeout(function() {
  // set listener here
  // e.g. $("#ddS option").change(function(){ 
  //   ddS_SelectedIndexChanged()
  // });
}, 1);
```

Comment: what do i have to do insie settimeout function?

Comment: Can i call out to my cs event from jquery like you gave in ur example?